# GWT: Change padding of tree rows?

Tags: java, css, gwt, tree

A GWT tree looks roughly like this:

```
<div class="gwt-Tree">
    <div style="padding-top: 3px; padding-right: 3px;
                padding-bottom: 3px; margin-left: 0px;
                padding-left: 23px;">
         <div style="display:inline;" class="gwt-TreeItem">
              <table>
                   ...
              </table>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div ...>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

My question is: how should I change the padding of the individual tree rows? I suppose I could do something along the lines of setting CSS rules for `.gwt-Tree > div` but that seems hacky. Is there a more elegant way?

---

**Resolution:** Apparently there is NOT a more elegant way. Here is what we did, FWIW:

```
 .gwt-Tree > div:first-child { 
      width: 0px !important; 
      height: 0px !important; 
      margin: 0px !important; 
      padding: 0px !important; 
 } 

 .gwt-Tree > div {
      padding: 0px 5px !important;
 }

 .gwt-Tree > div[hidefocus=true] {
      width: 0px !important;
      height: 0px !important;

      margin: 0px !important;
      padding: 0px !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .gwt-Tree {background:green;}
    .gwt-Tree div {padding-top: 3px; padding-right: 3px;padding-bottom: 3px; margin-left: 0px;padding-left: 23px;background:gray;}
    .gwt-Tree div .gwt-TreeItem {padding:0;margin:0;background:red;color:#fff;}
    </style> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="gwt-Tree">
    <div>
         <div class="gwt-TreeItem">
            random
         </div>
    </div>
    <div>
         <div class="gwt-TreeItem">
            random
         </div>
    </div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Note that .gwt-Tree div will affect all child divs, so you have to reset them back to the style you want with .gwt-Tree div .gwtTreeItem.

About the "hacky >" you said - > selector is supported in all browsers except for IE6 who won't recognize it.

Comment: sorry i don't think that's what i'm looking for: that allows me to customize the CSS of the first or third level div, but not the second-level div, the one with the padding...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and tried as well to solve it with CSS, but no luck.
Finally I managed to change the top and bottom padding in the java code:

```
/**
    * handle top and bottom padding issue of leafs the grandparent DOM element (div) has disturbing top and bottom
    * padding of 3px, which is changed here to 0px
    * 
    * @param uiObject
    *           uiObject which is a leaf in the tree
    */
   private static void correctStyle(final UIObject uiObject) {
      if (uiObject instanceof TreeItem) {
         if (uiObject != null && uiObject.getElement() != null) {
            Element element = uiObject.getElement();
            element.getStyle().setPaddingBottom(0, Unit.PX);
            element.getStyle().setPaddingTop(0, Unit.PX);
         }
      } else {
         if (uiObject != null && uiObject.getElement() != null && uiObject.getElement().getParentElement() != null
               && uiObject.getElement().getParentElement().getParentElement() != null
               && uiObject.getElement().getParentElement().getParentElement().getStyle() != null) {
            Element element = uiObject.getElement().getParentElement().getParentElement();
            element.getStyle().setPaddingBottom(0, Unit.PX);
            element.getStyle().setPaddingTop(0, Unit.PX);
         }
      }
   }
```

I use the method like this in the code:

```
Anchor fileDownloadLink = new Anchor();
fileDownloadLink.setStyleName(ViewConstants.STYLE_LINK_FILE_DOWNLOAD);
fileDownloadLink.setText(subSubStructure.getName());
fileDownloadLink.setHref(ViewConstants.HREF_DOWNLOAD_FILE_EXTRACTED_DATA + subSubStructure.getPath());
treeItem.addItem(fileDownloadLink);
StyleCorrector.correctStyle(fileDownloadLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the GWT [Tree Documentation](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Tree.html).  The CSS style rules for the tree and tree items are

> **CSS Style Rules**
>
> **.gwt-Tree**
>   the tree itself
>
> **.gwt-Tree .gwt-TreeItem**
>   a tree item
>
> **.gwt-Tree .gwt-TreeItem-selected**
>   a selected tree item

You probably want to add the padding to **.gwt-Tree .gwt-TreeItem** and to **.gwt-Tree .gwt-TreeItem-selected**

Comment: The question was not about the TreeItem div, but the div between the Tree and the TreeItem.

Comment: @gamma ... The page i reference to lists the TreeItem and Tree.  So the div/css name for the TreeItem is listed there.  Its also listed in the text of my answer.  Read the entire doc before down voting.

Comment: @Carnell unfortunately Gamma is right though: if you see my question, you'll see three levels: the tree (gwt-tree), the second level with the padding that I want to change, and the treeitem (gwt-treeitem). And the question is about styling the div which CONTAINS the treeitem.

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing anything with the div in between the gwt-Tree and the gwt-TreeItem.  This is just an extra div that could eaisly go away in future GWT releases.  Also from your example it looks like there is always only one get-TreeItem div contained within this middle div.  If this is the case using either this middle div or the get-TreeItem would have similar behavior.

Comment: @Carnell The problem is that setting padding on gwt-TreeItem does not change the padding of the tree items! The padding is still defined by the surrounding div.

Comment: @Epaga If that is the case it sounds like there is a GWT bug.  You should open one up at http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/list